# How to split a string AFTER every substring in Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a long text with companies and IDs. I would like to split the string into a list, where an item ends with an ID. Every ID consists of 5 digits and appears in the text in the same format `\(ID\:\d{5}\)`

`text = "Company A, Inc(ID:12345), some-company, X (ID:12324), Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)"`

What I would like to get is the following:

`["Company A, Inc (ID:12345)", "some-company, X (ID:12324)", "Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)"]`

Is there a way to do it with Regex? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a=re.findall(r'(.*?\(ID\:\d{5}\))',text)
print(a)
```

output

```
['Company A, Inc(ID:12345)',
 ', some-company, X (ID:12324)',
 ', Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)']
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
import re
text = "Company A, Inc(ID:12345), some-company, X (ID:12324), Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)"

a = re.split(r'(?<=\(ID:\d{5}\)),\s*', text)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['Company A, Inc(ID:12345)', 'some-company, X (ID:12324)', 'Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)']
```

Explanation of the regex `r'(?<=\(ID:\d{5}\)),\s*'`:

- `(?<=pattern)` is a positive lookbehind assertion. It has the zero width and the matched substring remains in the split list.
- `\(ID:\d{5}\)` is the format as you describe.
- `,\s*` matches a comma followed by a zero or more whitespace(s). We do not want to include the substring in the result and it works as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally match a comma and 1 or more whitespace chars. Then match at least a single non whitespace char for the company name until the first occurrence of the id pattern.

Note that you don't have to escape the `\:`

```
(?:,\s+)?(\S.*?\(ID:\d{5}\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:,\s+)?` Optionally match a comma and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S.*?` Match a non whitespace char followed by 0* as least as possible chars
  - `\(ID:\d{5}\)` Match `(ID:` 5 digits and `)`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Of9rY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tmOo1R)

**Example**

```
import re

text = "Company A, Inc(ID:12345), some-company, X (ID:12324), Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)"
print(re.findall(r"(?:,\s+)?(\S.*?\(ID:\d{5}\))", text))
```

**Output**

`['Company A, Inc(ID:12345)', 'some-company, X (ID:12324)', 'Some Special Company Z (ID:34324)']`